# how to install a old version of gcc compiler from software manger and use it with plain "gcc" command?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gcc, matlab

I am struggling with the problem of Matlab mex compile. It needs specific old version of gcc compiler 4.4.6 . But in manager there is only 4.4 version. How could I specify it as 4.4.6? Or is it possible?

Next, I need to run it as gcc command. Currently my gcc command runs 4.7.2 version. How can I switch the gcc command to run the old version on Mint machine. Since installing only the compiler does not work for Matlab and it is calling plain gcc command.

Comment: Are you okay fully replacing your local version?  Or would you like side-by-side install of both?

Comment: side by side is more appropriate but I need to call it with needs to be default gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install the package `gcc-4.4` along with the other version of gcc. The next step would be to change the default `gcc` to this specific version. Most elegant and easy way is using `update-alternatives`. This is all explained in [this Stackoverflow.com answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7834049/1254292).